# How to plot ROC curves in multiclass classification?

Tags: classification, roc

In other words, instead of having a two class problem I am dealing with 4 classes and still would like to assess performance using AUC.

Comment: Is dimension reduction an option?

Comment: we have 4 classes, not really

Comment: [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka) does this perfectly, using the one against all class strategy.

Answer (score 66):

It seems you are looking for multi-class ROC analysis, which is a kind of multi-objective optimization covered in a [tutorial](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~flach/ICML04tutorial/) at ICML'04. As in several multi-class problem, the idea is generally to carry out pairwise comparison (one class vs. all other classes, one class vs. another class, see (1) or the *Elements of Statistical Learning*), and there is a recent paper by Landgrebe and Duin on that topic, [Approximating the multiclass ROC by pairwise analysis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.108.3250&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Pattern Recognition Letters 2007 28: 1747-1758. Now, for visualization purpose, I've seen some papers some time ago, most of them turning around [volume under the ROC surface](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.2427&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (VUS) or [Cobweb diagram](http://cskku.kkh.go.th/homework/ke/paper/visualization%20and%20analysis%20of%20classifiers%20performance%20in%20multi-class%20medical%20data.pdf).

I don't know, however, if there exists an R implementation of these methods, although I think the `stars()` function might be used for cobweb plot. I just ran across a Matlab toolbox that seems to offer multi-class ROC analysis, [PRSD Studio](http://doc.prsdstudio.com/latest/guide/ROC_analysis.html).

Other papers that may also be useful as a first start for visualization/computation:

- [Visualisation of multi-class ROC surfaces](http://users.dsic.upv.es/~flip/ROCML2005/papers/fieldsend2CRC.pdf)
- [A simplified extension of the Area under the ROC to the multiclass domain](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/a9p19/papers/prasa_06_vuc.pdf)

**References:**
1. Allwein, E.L., Schapire, R.E. and Singer, Y. (2000). Reducing multiclass to binary: A unifying approach for margin classifiers. *Journal of Machine Learning Research*, **1**:113–141.

Answer (score 12):

I recently found this [**pROC**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pROC/pROC.pdf) **package** in R which plots a **multiclass ROC** using the technique specified by [Hand and Till (2001)](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1010920819831.pdf). You can use the multiclass.roc function.

Answer (score 12):

You need to specify your classifier to act as one-vs-rest, and then you can plot individual ROC curves. There's a handy library for doing it without much work in python called `yellowbrick`.

Check out the docs with a minimal [reproducible example](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/classifier/rocauc.html#multi-class-rocauc-curves).

The result looks like this ([source](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-create-an-auc-roc-plot-for-a-multiclass-model-9e13838dd3de))

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The answers here are pretty complete, but I still would like to add my 5 cents. [In this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/110550/49130) you can find an example of R code for producing ROC Curves using One-Vs-All Approach and the [ROCR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROCR/index.html) R library.

This is the plot from that answer:

[image: ROC Curve]

Answer (score 6):

While the math is beyond me this general review article has some references you will likely be interested in, and has a brief description of multi-class ROC graphs.

An introduction to ROC analysis by Tom Fawcett
Pattern Recognition Letters
[Volume 27, Issue 8, June 2006, Pages 861-874](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.patrec.2005.10.010)

Link to [pdf](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.98.4088%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=nlx3TIq-LJCk4Abn_Li3Bg&usg=AFQjCNHO-_yjWAJrRVnJms7MbcqaJkd8eg&sig2=sqERq2v68UvOhJDMviOklg) as provided by gd047- thanks

Comment: I would say the same providing another link http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.98.4088%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=nlx3TIq-LJCk4Abn_Li3Bg&usg=AFQjCNHO-_yjWAJrRVnJms7MbcqaJkd8eg&sig2=sqERq2v68UvOhJDMviOklg

Comment: And here is another one, directly related to multi-class problem: Multi-class ROC analysis from a multi-objective optimisation perspective, Pattern Recognition Letters 2006 27(8): 918-927 (http://j.mp/9AMgzq).

Comment: Thanks for the other links, apparently that whole issue is popular, and its archive on science direct can be found here
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=PublicationURL&_tockey=%23TOC%235665%232006%23999729991%23621242%23FLA%23&_cdi=5665&_pubType=J&view=c&_auth=y&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=ece739626e7c50b228e85480cb2407e3