# Can I draw a single ROC curve for a test method applied onto a group of people with different levels (i.e., light, mild,sever) of sickness

Tags: probability, classification, roc, reliability

Can I draw a single ROC curve for a test method applied onto a group of people of different levels of sickness severity (i.e., light, mild, severe)? Or I need to draw three different ROC curves, one for each severity level? If the answer is yes, what is this kind of ROC experiment called? Thanks

Comment: Might be related to this question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/how-to-plot-roc-curves-in-multiclass-classification

Comment: Thanks Vincent, but that question is totally different.

Comment: I think you could give it a try: you have three classes, and this technique will allow you to draw ROC curves and compute AUCs. Sure it will not take into account the fact that your factor of interest is ordinal, but it's a start!

Comment: Thanks again Vincent, but I am trying to classify patients as either sick or healthy (i.e., two classes) but the patients actually of different sickness severity. Is it conceptually correct to assume that all patients are of same sickness level and draw a single ROC curve for the test method?

Comment: You need to add these important (and not obvious) details in your question.