# ROC AUC for multiclass problem

Tags: classification, model-evaluation, roc, auc, multi-class

Just some quick questions to clarify my doubt please.

I know that one can get `precision/recall` for each class in a multiclass problem, e.g. in this classification report:

```
Classification report
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.65      0.62      0.63     14601
           1       0.07      0.27      0.11      1398
           2       0.43      0.06      0.10      8317
           3       0.58      0.70      0.64     20301
           4       0.00      0.00      0.00       904

    accuracy                           0.53     45521
   macro avg       0.34      0.33      0.30     45521
weighted avg       0.55      0.53      0.51     45521
```

Accuracy is not computed as per class, since it's a global metric.

1. Can one also computes `ROC AUC` for each class.
2. What the difference between `macro/weighted avg precision/recall` and the value for each class. Is that representing a global measure of `precision/recall`?

Comment: this may give you some idea probably, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/how-to-plot-roc-curves-in-multiclass-classification

Comment: Please only ask one question per question...